# What were Bruce Lee diet plans and training schedule?

Tags: self-training, jeet-kune-do

I have heard a lot about Bruce Lee and how he put nutrition and protein intake in his diet plan, but there are too many unreliable sources that pretend to be truthful.

*I want to know how he managed to be able to perform at the peak stage and still be disciplined towards his diet and training, and what was his regimen?*

Comment: There are numerous articles on Bruce Lee's diet and supplement regimen. Most don't cite their sources, you're right. But the question I have is: Why does it matter? His knowledge came from what others at the time were saying to do, much like how people learn which supplements to take today. Trouble is, most of what they were doing in the 60's and early 70's are outdated and proved to be false. Most of what we know today is junk, too. Bruce Lee's physique was, I dare say, nothing special. Modern methods are probably going to get quicker and better results, because we know more now.

Comment: That could be, but still, everyone applies their inputs applicable with their current understanding of things. I thought maybe Bruce also applied some of his original things into his methods. And about today's info, its mostly garbage. There's too many things and majority seems true but in reality is false. Just saying. Peace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruce liked Chinese food and used to have a lot of variety in his food. I don't know much about the specifics of his diet.

His fitness recommendation from the Tao of Jeet Kune Do is as follows:

Monday, Wednesday, Friday

Skipping 
Forward Bend
Dand
Jumping Jack
Squat
High Kick

Waist Twisting
Palm-Up Curl
Roman Chair
Knee Drawing 
Side Bend
Palm-Down Curl

Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday

Groin Stretch
Side Leg Raise
Jumping Squat
Shoulder circling
Alternate splits
Leg stretch

Leg Raises
Reverse Curl
Sit-up Twist
Leverage Bar Twist
Alternate Leg Raise
Wrist Roller

Power Training

Press Lockout
Press Start
Rise on Toes
Pull
Squat
Shrug
Deadlift
Quarter Squat
Frog Kick

He used to warm up a particular part before intense exercise on that part and stretch it later. He used to exercise twice a day, more on which is written in the book.

I don't think he did all exercises mentioned above in a day. He used to vary them according to his mood. I have no idea about the power workout. He also believed that Indian wrestler workout of dand and baithak is quite complete as influenced by an Indian wrestler.

I personally do 2+2 of the above workouts 3 sets a day.
Eg. Monday
Skips (3x3 min)
Forward bend (Stretching :once)

Waist Twisting (Stretch)
Palm Up Curl (3 sets)

P.S. I highly recommend "The Tao of JKD". It's a beautiful book!